# PHP/MySQL - Dispatch Scheduler - Vertical Column

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing an application that needs to show appointments for salesman in a vertical column structure.  The closest thing I can find that would handle what I want to do nicely looks like this:

[image]

The salesmen's names are on top, and their appointments for the week are scheduled vertically.  There is also a nice blue heading for each day the salesman has an appointment (Thursday and Friday in this example).

This is how my MySQL `APPOINTMENTS` table is setup:
APPOINTMENTS Table:

```
======================================================================
   id   |   id_sales   |   id_lead   |   appt_date   |   appt_time   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    |   1          |   2         |   2013-12-26  |   11:00       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   2    |   1          |   3         |   2013-01-05  |   13:00       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   3    |   2          |   5         |   2013-12-27  |   13:00       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   4    |   2          |   6         |   2013-12-28  |   17:00       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   5    |   1          |   7         |   2013-12-29  |   19:30       |
======================================================================
```

`id_sales` refers to the salesmen's individual ID's (handled in another table) and `id_lead` refers to the appointments (also handled in another table).

As of right now, I don't need a complete explanation of how to handle every aspect of this task.  I am stuck, and don't know how to proceed.  I would be happy enough to get the salesmen's ID's as table headers, with the appointment id's (`id_lead`) underneath them.  I will try to figure out the rest once I get that piece working, with your help ;)

I will attach the non-working code I have come up with:

schedule.php:

```
...
<div id="schedule_wrapper_all">
  <?php print get_schedule_all(); ?>
</div>
...
```

db_functions.php:

```
function get_schedule_all() {
    $headers = get_table_headers();
    $schedule_builder = '';
    $schedule_builder .= '<table border="1">';
    $schedule_builder .= $headers;
    $schedule_builder .= '</table>';
    return $schedule_builder;
}

function get_table_headers() {
    include 'scripts/mysql_login_pdo.php';
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT `id_sales` FROM `appointments` ORDER BY `id_sales` ASC";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $appointments = '';
    $schedule_headers = '';
    $schedule_headers .= '<tr>';
    while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
        $id_sales = $row->id_sales;
        $schedule_headers .= "<th id='$id_sales'>$id_sales</th>";
        $appointments .= fill_appts($id_sales);
    }
    $schedule_headers .= '</tr>';
    $db = null;
    $schedule_headers .= $appointments;
    return $schedule_headers;
}

function fill_appts($id_sales) {
    include 'scripts/mysql_login_pdo.php';
    $query = "SELECT `id_lead` FROM `appointments` WHERE `id_sales` = :id_sales";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':id_sales' => $id_sales
    ));

    $schedule_appts = '';
    $schedule_appts .= '<tr>';
    while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
        $id_lead = $row->id_lead;
        $schedule_appts .= "<td>$id_lead</td>";
    }
    $schedule_appts .= '</tr>';
    $db = null;
    return $schedule_appts;
}
```

Screenshot of result:
[image]

Thanks again for any help!

------------------------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------------
Got it working.  Needs a lot of styling, but it's a start in the right direction.

[image]

```
function get_schedule_all() {
    $headers = get_table_headers();
    $appointments = appointments();
    $schedule_builder = '';
    $schedule_builder .= '<table>';
    $schedule_builder .= $headers;
    $schedule_builder .= $appointments;
    $schedule_builder .= '</table>';
    return $schedule_builder;
}

function get_table_headers() {
    include 'scripts/mysql_login_pdo.php';
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT `id_sales` FROM `appointments` ORDER BY `id_sales` ASC";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $schedule_headers = '';
    $schedule_headers .= '<tr>';
    while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
        $id_sales = $row->id_sales;
        $schedule_headers .= "<td id='$id_sales'>$id_sales</td>";
    }
    $schedule_headers .= '</tr>';
    $db = null;
    return $schedule_headers;
}

function fill_appts($id_sales) {
    include 'scripts/mysql_login_pdo.php';
    $query = "SELECT `id_lead` FROM `appointments` WHERE `id_sales` = :id_sales";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':id_sales' => $id_sales
    ));

    $schedule_appts = '';
    $schedule_appts .= '<table>';
    while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
        $id_lead = $row->id_lead;
        $schedule_appts .= "<tr><td class='appt'>$id_lead</td></tr>";
    }
    $schedule_appts .= '</table>';
    $db = null;
    return $schedule_appts;
}

function appointments(){
    include 'scripts/mysql_login_pdo.php';
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT `id_sales` FROM `appointments` ORDER BY `id_sales` ASC";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $appointments = '';
    $appointments .= '<tr>';
    while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
        $id_sales = $row->id_sales;
        $appointments .= '<td>';
        $appointments .= fill_appts($id_sales);
        $appointments .= '</td>';
    }
    $appointments .= '</tr>';
    $db = null;
    return $appointments;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is instead of `<td>$id_lead</td>`,  create another `<table>` inside each cell of id sales and then use `<tr><td>$id_lead</td></tr>` that way each $id_lead will be a row below id_sales.

That way you'll have 2,3,and 7 as 3 rows in a table, inside the cell of id_sales 1. And 5,6 as 2 rows in a table, inside the cell of id_sales 2.

Comment: Ah.. Good idea.  Thank you.  Is there any performance hit going this route?

Comment: no you should be able to use the same queries as you have now.

Comment: You can edit your question with updated code once that works, so it might help others too :)

Comment: I would love to see a screenshot of your finished product :)

Comment: Will do!  It's part of a much larger application to track sales leads for a heating and cooling company.  I plan on open sourcing the entire project once complete.

Comment: You could just not use tables all together.

Comment: @FreshPrinceofSO, How could I accomplish this without tables?  I don't need a full explanation, but a few research topics would help immensely.  Thanks.

Comment: @WillDavis Using CSS; `<div>`s

Comment: True.  Would I see any performance increases ditching the tables?  There may be a max of 50 columns, with a max of 50 appointments in any given salesman's week (column).  (Would be a max total of 2500 `div`s)