# PHP/MySQL - Schedule Appointments Underneath Proper Weekday

Tags: php, mysql

-----UPDATE-----
Big thanks to @Tin Tran.  Here is the working code for anyone interested:
db_functions.php:

```
function fill_appts($id_sales) {
include '../scripts/mysql_login_pdo.php';

$query = "SELECT leads.fname,
   leads.lname,
   leads.addr_city,
   appointments.appt_date,
   appointments.appt_time,
   appointments.id_lead,
   d.dayDesc
FROM (      SELECT 'Monday' as dayDesc,1 as dayOrder
  UNION SELECT 'Tuesday',          2
  UNION SELECT 'Wednesday',        3
  UNION SELECT 'Thursday',         4
  UNION SELECT 'Friday',           5
  UNION SELECT 'Saturday',         6
  UNION SELECT 'Sunday',           7
  )as d
LEFT JOIN appointments ON (DAYNAME(appointments.appt_date) = d.dayDesc)
INNER JOIN leads ON (leads.id = appointments.id_lead)
WHERE MONTH(appointments.appt_date) = MONTH(NOW())
AND appointments.id_sales = :id_sales
ORDER BY appointments.appt_date ASC,appointments.appt_time ASC,d.dayOrder ASC";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':id_sales' => $id_sales
));

$lastDay = '';
$last_appt_date = '';
$schedule_appts = '';
$schedule_appts .= '<table class="appointments">';

while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {

    $id_lead = $row->id_lead;
    $fname = $row->fname;
    $lname = $row->lname;
    $addr_city = $row->addr_city;
    $appt_date = $row->appt_date;
    $appt_time = $row->appt_time;
    $dayName = $row->dayDesc;

    if (($dayName != $lastDay) && ($appt_date != $last_appt_date)) {
        $schedule_appts .= "<tr class='weekday' value='$appt_date'><td>" . date('l m/d', strtotime($appt_date)) . "</td></tr>";
    }

    $schedule_appts .= "<tr id='$id_lead'><td><div class='appt'>" .
            $fname . ' ' . $lname . '<br />' .
            $appt_date . '<br />' .
            $appt_time . "</div></td></tr>";
    $lastDay = $dayName;
    $last_appt_date = $appt_date;
}
$schedule_appts .= '</table>';
$db = null;
return $schedule_appts;
```

}

RESULT:
[image]
-----END UPDATE-----

-----UPDATE-----
Worked on it a little this morning.  I get duplicate day names using the code I changed.  Any ideas on how to choose distinct weekdays?
[image]

db_functions.php:

```
...
function fill_appts($id_sales) {
    include '../scripts/mysql_login_pdo.php';
    $query = "SELECT `leads`.`fname`, "
            . "`leads`.`lname`, "
            . "`leads`.`addr_city`, "
            . "`appointments`.`appt_date`, "
            . "`appointments`.`appt_time`, "
            . "`appointments`.`id_lead` "
            . "FROM `leads`,`appointments` "
            . "WHERE `leads`.`id` = `appointments`.`id_lead` "
            . "AND MONTH(`appointments`.`appt_date`) = MONTH(NOW()) "
            . "AND `appointments`.`id_sales` = :id_sales "
            . "ORDER BY `appointments`.`appt_time` ASC";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':id_sales' => $id_sales
    ));

    $schedule_appts = '';
    $schedule_appts .= '<table class="appointments">';

    while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
        $id_lead = $row->id_lead;
        $fname = $row->fname;
        $lname = $row->lname;
        $addr_city = $row->addr_city;
        $appt_date = $row->appt_date;
        $appt_time = $row->appt_time;
//------------------------Problematic area-----------------------
        $schedule_appts .= "<tr class='weekday' value='$appt_date'><td>" . date('l', strtotime($appt_date)) . "</td></tr>";
//---------------------------------------------------------------
        $schedule_appts .= "<tr id='$id_lead'><td><div class='appt'>" .
                $fname . ' ' . $lname . '<br />' .
                $appt_date . '<br />' .
                $appt_time . "</div></td></tr>";
    }
    $schedule_appts .= '</table>';
    $db = null;
    return $schedule_appts;
}
...
```

-----END UPDATE-----

This is a continuation from the following post:
[PHP/MySQL - Dispatch Scheduler - Vertical Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941690/php-mysql-dispatch-scheduler-vertical-column)

I am getting much closer to my goal, as outlined in the previous post.  I am at the point where I want the appointments to stack vertically underneath the appropriate weekday.  I'll show an image of what I have, and what I want, seeing as that will be many times easier to understand.

What I've got:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Here is the code I have, which produces the first image.  I pointed out where I believe my issue is, within the 'fill_appts' function:
schedule.php:

```
...
<div id="schedule_wrapper_all">
  <?php print get_schedule_all(); ?>
</div>
...
```

db_functions.php:

```
function get_schedule_all() {
    $headers = get_table_headers();
    $appointments = appointments();
    $schedule_builder = '';
    $schedule_builder .= '<table class="appt_table">';
    $schedule_builder .= $headers;
    $schedule_builder .= $appointments;
    $schedule_builder .= '</table>';
    return $schedule_builder;
}
function get_table_headers() {
    include '../scripts/mysql_login_pdo.php';
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT `appointments`.`id_sales`,`users`.`fname`,`users`.`lname` "
            . "FROM `appointments`,`users` "
            . "WHERE `appointments`.`id_sales` = `users`.`id` "
            . "ORDER BY `appointments`.`id_sales` ASC";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $schedule_headers = '';
    $schedule_headers .= '<tr>';
    while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
        $id_sales = $row->id_sales;
        $fname = $row->fname;
        $lname = $row->lname;
        $schedule_headers .= "<th id='$id_sales'>" . $fname . ' ' . $lname . "</th>";
    }
    $schedule_headers .= '</tr>';
    $db = null;
    return $schedule_headers;
}
function fill_appts($id_sales) {
    include '../scripts/mysql_login_pdo.php';
    $query = "SELECT `leads`.`fname`, "
            . "`leads`.`lname`, "
            . "`leads`.`addr_city`, "
            . "`appointments`.`appt_date`, "
            . "`appointments`.`appt_time`, "
            . "`appointments`.`id_lead` "
            . "FROM `leads`,`appointments` "
            . "WHERE `leads`.`id` = `appointments`.`id_lead` "
            . "AND MONTH(`appointments`.`appt_date`) = MONTH(NOW()) "
            . "AND `appointments`.`id_sales` = :id_sales "
            . "ORDER BY `appointments`.`appt_time` ASC";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':id_sales' => $id_sales
    ));

    $schedule_appts = '';
    $schedule_appts .= '<table class="appointments">';
    $schedule_appts .= get_weekdays();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
        $id_lead = $row->id_lead;
        $fname = $row->fname;
        $lname = $row->lname;
        $addr_city = $row->addr_city;
        $appt_date = $row->appt_date;
        $appt_time = $row->appt_time;
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//THIS IS WHERE I BELIEVE I NEED TO LOOP THROUGH RESULTS AGAIN:
//        foreach ($day as $weekday){
        $schedule_appts .= "<tr id='$id_lead'><td><div class='appt'>" .
                $fname . ' ' . $lname . '<br />' .
                $appt_date . '<br />' .
                $appt_time . "</div></td></tr>";
//        }
//END LOOP
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
    }
    $schedule_appts .= '</table>';
    $db = null;
    return $schedule_appts;
}
function appointments() {
    include '../scripts/mysql_login_pdo.php';
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT `id_sales` FROM `appointments` ORDER BY `id_sales` ASC";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $appointments = '';
    $appointments .= '<tr>';
    while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
        $id_sales = $row->id_sales;
        $appointments .= '<td>';
        $appointments .= fill_appts($id_sales);
        $appointments .= '</td>';
    }
    $appointments .= '</tr>';
    $db = null;
    return $appointments;
}

function get_weekdays() {
    $monday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('monday this week'));
    $tuesday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('tuesday this week'));
    $wednesday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('wednesday this week'));
    $thursday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('thursday this week'));
    $friday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('friday this week'));
    $saturday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('saturday this week'));
    $sunday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('sunday this week'));
    $week = "<tr class='weekday' value='$monday'><td>Monday</td></tr>"
            . "<tr class='weekday' value='$tuesday'><td>Tuesday</td></tr>"
            . "<tr class='weekday' value='$wednesday'><td>Wednesday</td></tr>"
            . "<tr class='weekday' value='$thursday'><td>Thursday</td></tr>"
            . "<tr class='weekday' value='$friday'><td>Friday</td></tr>"
            . "<tr class='weekday' value='$saturday'><td>Saturday</td></tr>"
            . "<tr class='weekday' value='$sunday'><td>Sunday</td></tr>";
    return $week;
}
```

As you can see in my functions, this shows all appointments for all employees within a given month.  I am ok with the script generating the weekday names for every day of the month, or dynamically where it will only generate the weekday if an appointment is scheduled for that day.  I wrote the 'get_weekdays' function based around a single week, which will need to be updated to check for each day within a month.  If that part is too much, I'll keep researching for the answer.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.  As with the last post, I'm not looking for someone to write the function for me, just give me a kick in the right direction ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at the [DAYNAME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) function. Then maybe instead of getting all weekdays just get one at a time and loop through your result set to see if it's the same day and print it out.
To reset to the beginning of the result set, you could use http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

as mentioned in my comment: try this below query and see

```
SELECT leads.fname,
       leads.lname,
       leads.addr_city,
       appointments.appt_date,
       appointments.appt_time,
       appointments.id_lead,
       d.dayDesc
FROM (      SELECT 'Monday' as dayDesc,1 as dayOrder
      UNION SELECT 'Tuesday',          2
      UNION SELECT 'Wednesday',        3
      UNION SELECT 'Thursday',         4
      UNION SELECT 'Friday',           5
      UNION SELECT 'Saturday',         6
      UNION SELECT 'Sunday',           7
      )as d
LEFT JOIN appointments ON (DAYNAME(appointments.appt_date) = d.dayDesc)
INNER JOIN leads ON (leads.id = appointments.id_lead)
WHERE MONTH(appointments.appt_date) = MONTH(NOW())
AND appointments.id_sales = :id_sales
ORDER BY d.dayOrder ASC,appointments.appt_time ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for this info.  I think I will go this route if what I just updated doesn't work.

Comment: or what you can do too is LEFT JOIN a hardcoded `(SELECT 'Sunday' as dayDesc,1 as dayOrder UNION SELECT 'Monday',2 UNION SELECT 'Tuesday',3 ... SELECT 'Saturday',7)` LEFT JOIN with your data and then `ORDER BY dayOrder` at the very end so when you get resultset, loop over it, setting a variable to default to blank and then print out the dayDesc if the variable is not equal to the current row's dayDesc, and then print out the appointments's details if they're not null, and then set the variable to dayDesc at end of loop, that way you only loop through your resultset once.

Comment: It's a bummer that I only understand like 30% of what you said ;).  No offense to you, of course.  I will do some reading up.  I think I get the gist of what you are suggesting though. As I am weak on JOINs, I guess it's time to learn.  Thanks buddy.

Comment: check my answer, i updated it with a query try that one and see what i mean.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.  I am working through your last comment.  Your query was much appreciated.  I will attempt to loop through the results and will post back if there are issues (or success).  Thanks again!

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar @Tin Tran.  Thanks for your assistance.  I updated my post with the working code.